# Play local audio on cordova in Meteor 1.3

Tags: cordova, meteor

So I have an audio file `/public/sound.mp3`. I would like to play it using the [cordova media plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media)

```
new Media('/sound.mp3').play()
```

but that does not work. What is the local url that I should pass?

**Update**

I have found out that meteor 1.3 serves assets locally on cordova through

```
http://localhost:<port>/path/to/asset
```

where `<port>` is a number between 12000 and 13000 randomly generated from the appId. You can find out what it is by calling `document.location.origin` on cordova. Then you can concat the asset path:

```
var path = document.location.origin + '/sound.mp3'
// evaluates to e.g. http://localhost:12272/sound.mp3
```

Now we should be able to pass it to Media, right?

```
new Media(path).play() // works on Android, but not on iOS
```

I know that the path is actually correct on both Android and iOS, because I tested the path by writing `document.location.href = path` which navigates the browser to the actual sound file. Any ideas on what could cause this behaviour on iOS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [buzz.js](http://buzz.jaysalvat.com/), install via npm or use the `brentjanderson:buzz` package. Now place your sound `sound.mp3` into meteor's `/public` folder and then play the audio like this:

`new buzz.sound('/sound.mp3').play()`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know cordova media plugin but when you put file in "public" folder, no need to specify.

I think this code is correct :

new Media('sound.mp3').play()

Comment: I have updated the original post and written down what I found out about the URL of local assets. Problem not solved for iOS yet.

Comment: @kristjaningi No, I haven't! Still haven't found a way to play local audio in cordova on iOS!

Comment: @Pueggel Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @msj121 yes I ended up using buzz.js via the brentjanderson:buzz. Simply put your sound.mp3 in /public folder and then do this: 

new buzz.sound('/sound.mp3').play()